# "Unsupported type" warning when using UNION ALL SQL statement with Oracle OleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, oledb, union

I've got this strange error that I just can't explain...

I have a software that was using ODBC as main connector for the last years. Now the software allows to use OleDB too, which I would prefer for several reasons.
Now the funny thing is:
The SQL query that is perfectly working with the Oracle ODBC driver does *not* work with the Oracle OleDB driver.
For one I have to cast every numeric value with CAST AS, but that's the easy part I already put behind me. So when run seperately, the queries are working now. However as soon as I do a "UNION ALL" with these queries, I get an "unsupported type" warning from the software - just as if I had forgotten to CAST the numeric value(s).
Sadly I don't get any more debug information from the software, but my guess is that somehow the SQL statement has to be altered for the Oracle OleDB driver.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  string1 AS Name1
  string2 AS Name2
  CAST (int1 AS INT) AS Year
  CAST (int2 AS INT) AS Period
FROM
  database1
WHERE
  int1 = 2017 AND int2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  string1 AS Name1
  string2 AS Name2
  CAST (int1 AS INT) AS Year
  CAST (int2 AS INT) AS Period
FROM
  database2
WHERE
  int1 = 2017 AND int2 = 1
```

Has anyone ever ran into a problem like that?

Comment: Please show what the *actual* error says.  Describing the error isn't helpful at all.

Comment: Clearly the string columns have incompatible types.

Comment: Like I said: the software (closed source commercial programm) does not give me more information than a error popup with "Field YEAR is of an unsupported type". It's the same error as when not casting numeric values at all. However run alone, the CASTed queries do work.
The error is always displayed for the numeric values - if I leave out Year, the I get the error for Period and so on...

Comment: Which OleDB provider do you use? The Microsoft or the Oracle one?

Comment: YEAR is a reserved word in OleDb. Try "[Year]" instead of "Year" or name it different, if possible.

Comment: Oh, bad example: "Year" is not the actual name that is used, it's just something I came up with for my example. So that can't be it. And I am using the Oracle OleDB provider since Microsoft doesn't suggest to use theirs any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out nothing was wrong with my query - it looks like a bug in the software, as the exact same query is working just fine (even without CAST) in Excel (with the same OleDB provider etc.). Well, trying another program could have saved me quite some hours of work.

Anyway I'd like to thank all of you for trying to help me!

Answer (score -1):

YEAR is a reserved word in OleDb. Try "[Year]" instead of "Year" or name it different, if possible.

```
SELECT
  string1 AS Name1,
  string2 AS Name2,
  CAST (int1 AS INT) AS [Year],
  CAST (int2 AS INT) AS Period
FROM
  database1
WHERE
  int1 = 2017 AND int2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  string1 AS Name1,
  string2 AS Name2,
  CAST (int1 AS INT) AS [Year],
  CAST (int2 AS INT) AS Period
FROM
  database2
WHERE
  int1 = 2017 AND int2 = 1
```